# How do I slow down my matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to plot a line and I've three points for it which are in two lists: x,y.
The code works but I can't see the line being rendered in front of me and hence, it keeps looking like an image. How do I slow down this animation?
Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 105), ylim=(0, 68))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x = np.array([23.94, 34.65, 28.14])
    y = np.array([5.984, 6.664, 6.256])  
    #x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    #y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=1, interval=1, save_count = 50, blit=True)


FFWriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
#ani.save('particle_box.avi', writer = FFWriter)
#anim.save('basic.mp4',  writer = FFWriter)#, fps=30)#, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first, your animation has only two effective states because the animation function isn't actually doing anything.

You can factor out the definition of `x` and `y` since they don't actually change. To actually perform the animation, what you should do is make the *points* on the line change with every call of `anim_func`, which can be done by *slicing* `x` and `y`:

```
x = np.array([23.94, 34.65, 28.14])
y = np.array([5.984, 6.664, 6.256])  

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
```

Lastly, you should modify your `FuncAnimation` creation to have a longer interval, for example:

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                              interval=1000, save_count = 50, blit=True)
```

Comment: @Sheldore Ready enough, I hope :thinking:

Comment: Why did I not have to slice the x,y for the sin curve (the very next two lines that have been commented out) because that's where I got the code from?

Comment: It's not really about slicing specifically, but about making the output of `anim_func` *dependent upon `i`*. Look at the call to `np.sin`.

Comment: @gmda How do I control the linewidth and colour and other such parameters in this? For instance, I'd want the first line to be dotted and the second to be a solid line. Is that achievable?

Comment: @Abhishek You can just set the line parameters as you would normally, since you're just modifying an existing `Line2D` artist (if you still have problems, I would suggest you ask a new question).

Comment: What exactly is the 'i' here? I see it hasn't been defined anywhere and yet it works.

Comment: It’s a parameter of the animation function, and represents the frame number.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 105), ylim=(0, 68))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
import math
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

x = np.array([])
y = np.array([])

for i in range(1000):
    x = np.append(x, i)
    y = np.append(y, 10 + 10 * math.sin(i / 10))

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(x), interval=1, save_count = 50, blit=True)


FFWriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
#ani.save('particle_box.avi', writer = FFWriter)
#anim.save('basic.mp4',  writer = FFWriter)#, fps=30)#, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I understand now. However, my intention isn't to create a sine wave but a plot for a certain object moving through an area randomly